# Python: Search for String in Filenames

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi

I have been trying to search the root file system for a certain string (in the middle of the filename or wherever).  I read about grep and I have tried this code here:

```
grep -rnw /home/pi/music -e "Maroon"
```

and something strange happens, there are three filenames with Maroon in them (same capitalization and spacing), but only two show up in the terminal.  Any ideas why that is?  Are there any other, easier ways to do this?

I would also like to say that I saw this StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473093/check-if-the-filename-contains-a-string-python), but I could not get it to work.  I believe that was focusing on specific filenames, while I would like to do a general search.

All help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "show up in the terminal"?

Comment: @Cody try `grep -rn "Maroon" /home/pi/music`

Comment: @AvinashRaj This is very interesting again, it only shows two results (there are three) however X-Istence's answer works perfectly... Very weird, thanks for the response!

Comment: `find /home/pi/music -type f -print | grep -e "Maroon"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` reads through the files on your disk, and searches for the word "Maroon".

What I think you want (when searching for file names) is:

```
find /home/pi/music -iname "*maroon*"
```

This will display all files that are named `*maroon*` (case insensitive). If you want case sensitive, take a look at `-name`.

```
man find
```

Will list all options for `find`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct (or rather, the more common) way to search for files in matching a certain pattern is to use the `find` command, like this:

```
find /home/pi/music -type f -iname "*maroon*" -ls
```

- `type`, limit searches to a particular type, in this case `f` for regular files (so it will ignore directories, pipes, sockets, etc.)
- `iname` case insensitive name search
- `ls` list the files found.

`grep` is used to search *within* files for matching content.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  When I enter this in, it doesn't give back anything?  Is there a way I can print out this to the terminal?  Thanks again!

Comment: Add `-ls` to the end.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid you don't need to add `-ls` at the last.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use find to search for filenames

```
find /home/pi/music -depth 1 -name \*Maroon\*
```

This will find a file where the name contains the string.  You need to quote the filename, so the shell doesn't glob it.  -depth 1 so you only search the current directory